Issues Installing Various Linux Distros on AMD Ryzen 7 5700U Mini PC
(acknowledging the post here that seems to mention this issue to some extent, with a plethora of other posts on other sites attempting to debug this problem)
I have a Ryzen 7 5700U Mini PC that I've been able to dual-boot Ubuntu MATE and Windows 11 with (as that is the goal), but I have an issue that seems to be consistent with others in that any new/recent version of the Linux kernel seems to not function on the machine. Or, at least that's what I initially thought.  After some troubleshooting, I was able to determine that (1) the system isn't dead - there's just no video (the keyboard seems to respond to things, and the system boots fully when sent to recovery mode using any kernel), and (2) any kernel <=6.2 actually does work (verified with Ubuntu MATE, Linux Mint Debian Edition and others).  I'd love to run a current kernel and wonder if this is some sort of regression from a video driver standpoint. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Display using a different port.... no gpu drivers installed.... monitor being driven at wrong resolution/fps.... And you have seemed to have looked at any of the logs, including /var/log/X*.log etc.
